# Will trees continue to grow if I don't cut them down completely?

Tags: terraria

I get bored of cutting down trees and having to go re-seed the world with acorns. Then I had a brainwave and decided to cut down the tree but leave the stump in place, like so:

[image: Tree Stumps]

So, will these grow back? I did this a little while ago and there appears to be no signs of regrowth (although this is possibly because of the corruption). If that doesn't work, if I cut them a little higher, leaving say 2-3 blocks, will that help instead?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. Once the tree has grown, it is done growing forever. You will need to clear space on the ground and plant acorns if you want more wood.

Comment: Note that the jungle will grow new trees without using acorns. Also, corrupt, snowy, and jungle trees will not drop any acorns when cut.

Comment: That's interesting to know! I may do all my farming in the Jungle then and hopefully it will be self sustaining with no effort on my part.